# WaitForSeconds not working in "custom" coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

iam writing my own CoroutineScheduler which looks (simplified) like this:

```
void Start()
{
    cr = test();
}

void Update()
{
    cr.MoveNext();
}

IEnumerator test()
{
    int i = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        print(i++);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    }
}
```

The problem is that my function doesnt print a number every 3 seconds, but every frame.

Is this because i dont use StartCoroutine() or is there another problem?

Comment: Yes if you dont start it as a coroutine it doesnt  follow those coroutines principals

Answer (score 1):

You do not start the coroutine. Either do

```
IEnumerator Start() 
{
   return test();
}
```

or

```
void Start() 
{
   StartCoroutine(test());
}
```

edit: Calling cr.MoveNext() will just move the enumerator to the next entry without applying the WaitForSeconds logic

Comment: is there a way to write a custom yield instruction which does WaitForSeconds? I tried it but it doesnt work as specified in the documentation:https://pastebin.com/kMjkmsrP

Comment: It's not the yield instruction you need to write your own executor. But what are you trying to achieve?